# How to understand this sentence within Atiyah-Macdonald's textbook about commutative algebra

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra

In page 102 of this textbook, authors mentioned that:

Assume topological group $G$ has a fundamental system of neighborhoods consisting of subgroups as:
$G= G_0 \supseteq G_1 \supseteq\cdots\supseteq G_n\supseteq\cdots$, which determine a unique topology in $G$

and (??) $U\subseteq G$ is a neighborhood of $0$ if and only if it contains some $G_n$.

How to understand this sentence? Cause in $p$-adic numbers, if we consider $U=\{p\}\cup p^3\mathbb{Z}$, you can see $U$ is not an open subset, since $p$ has no neighborhood within $U$ as $p+G_n$ for some integer $n$.

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: What's the problem with $U$ not being an open subset in the $p$-adic topology? A-M say that $U$ is a *neighborhood* of $0$ if contains some $G_n$, not that $U$ is open.

Comment: so what's your understanding about "neighborhood of 0" here. I took it mistakenly as open subset contain zero...

Comment: A  neighborhood of $0$ is a subset $U$ of $G$ which contains some $G_n$ (as the textbook says).

Comment: In general a neighbourhood of a point is a set, which contains an open set, that contains thr point. So any supset of an open neighborhood is just called neighborhood.

Comment: thanks a lot.  your answers are helpful